# Exporting specific string from pdf file using PDFbox

Tags: java, string, pdf, extract, pdfbox

I use this code for extracting the text of pdf file and saving into a txt file:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.*;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.*;

public class PDFtest {

 public static void main(String[] args){
 PDDocument pd;
 BufferedWriter wr;

 try {
         File input = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\1212.pdf");
         File output = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\parse.txt"); 
         pd = PDDocument.load(input);
         System.out.println(pd.getNumberOfPages());
         System.out.println(pd.isEncrypted());
         PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
         stripper.setStartPage( 1 );
         stripper.setEndPage( 4 );
         wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(output)));
         stripper.writeText(pd, wr);
         if (pd != null) {
             pd.close();
         }

        wr.close();
 } catch (Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
        } 
     }
}
```

I want to extract a specific string from the pdf file. For example the pdf file contains the following text:

> Unicode Converter enables you to easily convert Unicode characters to
>   their Unicode and decimal representations.
>
> As you type in one of the text boxes below, the other boxes are
>   converted on the fly.
>
> The Unicode converter doesn't automatically add spaces between the
>   converted values. You can use the add spaces button to separate the
>   Unicode characters so that the converted values will also be separated
>   from one another.
>
> Whitespace characters are not converted unless the whitespace checkbox
>   is checked.

Let's say i want to extract the strings:

> Unicode Converter enables you to easily convert Unicode characters to
>   their Unicode and decimal representations.

and

> The Unicode converter doesn't automatically add spaces between the
>   converted values. You can use the add spaces button to separate the
>   Unicode characters so that the converted values will also be separated
>   from one another.

Can anyone give any help on this?

Comment: According to which information do you want to identify the strings? Does the PDF have some markers? Do you have some regular expression? Do you have some coordinates of regions to extract from?

Comment: in my example i want to extract the strings that start with "Unicode" or "The Unicode" and ends with "." or "\n".

Comment: How about using regular expressions on the text output you have?

Comment: yes regular expressions sounds great. any kind of help is appreciated.